# How to return JSON from FastAPI (backend) using websockets to Vue (frontend)?

Tags: python, html, vue.js, websocket, fastapi

I have an application, in which the frontend is implemented in Vue and the backend uses FastAPI framework. The communication is achieved through websockets.

Currently, the frontend allows the user to enter a term, which is sent to the backend to generate the autocomplete and also perform a search on a URL that returns a JSON object. In which, I save this JSON object in the frontend folder. After that, the backend returns the autocomplete data for the term in question to the frontend. The frontend displays the aucomplete along with the json data.

However, when I studied a little more, I noticed that there is a way to send the JSON returned by the request URL to Vue (frontend), without having to save it locally, avoiding giving an error of not allowing to execute this process more than once.

My current code is as follows. For FastAPI (backend):

```py
@app.websocket("/")
async def predict_question(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        input_text = await websocket.receive_text()
        autocomplete_text = text_gen.generate_text(input_text)
        autocomplete_text = re.sub(r"[\([{})\]]", "", autocomplete_text)
        autocomplete_text = autocomplete_text.split()
        autocomplete_text = autocomplete_text[0:2]
        resp = req.get('www.description_url_search_='+input_text+'')
        datajson = resp.json()
        with open('/home/user/backup/AutoComplete/frontend/src/data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(datajson, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
        await websocket.send_text(' '.join(autocomplete_text))
```

File App.vue (frontend):

```html
<template>
  <div class="main-container">
    <h1 style="color:#0072c6;">Title</h1>
    <p style="text-align:center; color:#0072c6;">
      Version 0.1
      <br>
    </p>
    <Autocomplete />
    <br>
  </div>
  <div style="color:#0072c6;">
    <JsonArq />
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <img src="./components/logo-1536.png" width=250 height=200 alt="Logo" >
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Autocomplete from './components/Autocomplete.vue'
import JsonArq from './components/EstepeJSON.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Autocomplete, 
    JsonArq: JsonArq
  }
}
</script>

<style>

  .main-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Fredoka', sans-serif;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }

  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka&display=swap');
</style>
```

Autocomplete.vue file in the components directory:

```
<template>
<div class="pad-container">
  <div tabindex="1" @focus="setCaret" class="autocomplete-container">
    <span @input="sendText" @keypress="preventInput" ref="editbar" class="editable" contenteditable="true"></span>
    <span class="placeholder" contenteditable="false">{{autoComplete}}</span>    
  </div>
</div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Autocomplete',
  data: function() {
    return {
      autoComplete: "",
      maxChars: 75,
      connection: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const url = "ws://localhost:8000/"
    this.connection = new WebSocket(url);
    this.connection.onopen = () => console.log("connection established");
    this.connection.onmessage = this.receiveText;
  },
  methods: {
    setCaret() {
      const range= document.createRange()
      const sel = window.getSelection();
      const parentNode = this.$refs.editbar;

      if (parentNode.firstChild == undefined) {
        const emptyNode = document.createTextNode("");
        parentNode.appendChild(emptyNode);
      }

      range.setStartAfter(this.$refs.editbar.firstChild);
      range.collapse(true);
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
    },
    preventInput(event) {
      let prevent = false;      

      // handles capital letters, numbers, and punctuations input
      if (event.key == event.key.toUpperCase()) {
        prevent = true;
      }

      // exempt spacebar input
      if (event.code == "Space") {
        prevent = false;
      }

      // handle input overflow
      const nChars = this.$refs.editbar.textContent.length;
      if (nChars >= this.maxChars) {
        prevent = true;
      }

      if (prevent == true) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    },
    sendText() {
      const inputText = this.$refs.editbar.textContent;
      this.connection.send(inputText);
    },
    receiveText(event) {
      this.autoComplete = event.data;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

EstepeJSON.ue file in the components directory:

```
<template>
  <div width="80%" v-for="regList in myJson" :key="regList" class="container">
    <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Documento</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="countryList in regList[2]" :key="countryList">
            <td style="visibility: visible">{{ countryList}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"
  />
</template>

<script>
import json from "@/data.json";

export default {
  name: "EstepeJson",
  data() {
    return {
      myJson: json,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Example of the JSON returned by the URL:

```
[
{
"Title": "SOFT-STARTER", 
"Cod": "Produto: 15775931", 
"Description": "A soft-starter SSW7000 permite o controle de partida/parada e proteção de motores.", 
"Technical_characteristics": ["Corrente nominal", "600 A", "Tensão nominal", "4,16 kV", "Tensão auxiliar", "200-240 V", "Grau de proteção", "IP41", "Certificação", "CE"]
},
{
"Title": "SOFT-STARTER SSW", 
"Cod": "Produto: 14223395", 
"Description": "A soft-starter SSW7000 permite o controle de partida/parada e proteção de motores de indução trifásicos de média tensão.", 
"Technical_characteristics": ["Corrente nominal", "125 A", "Tensão nominal", "6,9 kV", "Tensão auxiliar", "200-240 V", "Grau de proteção", "IP54/NEMA12", "Certificação", "CE"]
}
]
```

Comment: what is the question exactly?

Comment: The frontend receives the term, sends it to the backend to generate autocomplete and return the suggested complete. I would like to use this term sent to the backend to make a request in a url that will return a json. This same json I want to return to the frontend, just like it already happens with autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your data to a json string with `json.dumps(mydata)`

Comment: I believe that the function within the FastAPI I have. I would like to understand how I am going to pass this data into Vue, through the Websockert.send_json() function, as explained in this topic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64101460/fast-api-sending-json-response-in-web-socket

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of using Python `requests` to make an HTTP request within a FastAPI application—the `requests` library's methods are blocking/synchronous, and thus, they would **block the event loop** when called directly; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details—I would strongly recommend using [`httpx`](https://www.python-httpx.org/), which offers an [`async` API](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/) as well. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) for more details and working examples.

Second, to send JSON `data` using `websockets`, you would need to use `await websocket.send_json(data)`, as explained in [Starlette's documentation](https://www.starlette.io/websockets/#sending-data). As shown in [Starlette's `websockets` source code](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/88e9fc1411f6bd79131afa4a7d2f4dc576c8bf04/starlette/websockets.py#L168), Starlette/FastAPI uses `text = json.dumps(data)`, in order to serialise the `data` you send, when calling the `send_json()` method. Hence, you would need to pass a Python `dict` object. Similar to `requests`, in `httpx`, you could call the `.json()` method on the response object to get the response data as a `dict` object, and then pass that dictionary to the `send_json()` function.

### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
from websockets.exceptions import ConnectionClosed
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
import httpx


html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>WebSocket Chat</h1>
        <form action="" onsubmit="sendMessage(event)">
            <input type="text" id="messageText" autocomplete="off"/>
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>
        <ul id='messages'>
        </ul>
        <script>
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws");
            ws.onmessage = function(event) {
                var messages = document.getElementById('messages')
                var message = document.createElement('li')
                var content = document.createTextNode(event.data)
                message.appendChild(content)
                messages.appendChild(message)
            };
            function sendMessage(event) {
                var input = document.getElementById("messageText")
                ws.send(input.value)
                input.value = ''
                event.preventDefault()
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
"""


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Initialise the Client on startup and add it to the state
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        yield {'client': client}
        # The Client closes on shutdown 


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get('/')
async def get():
    return HTMLResponse(html)
    

@app.websocket('/ws')
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    client = websocket.state.client
    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            # here, use httpx to issue a request, as demonstrated in the linked answers above
            r = await client.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
            await websocket.send_json(r.json())
    except (WebSocketDisconnect, ConnectionClosed):
        print("Client disconnected")
```

Comment: Hello friend, in parts your answer helped me a lot. I ended up studying about HTTPX after your recommendation and with that I was able to remove an error from the Request. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

using @Chris' tips on HTTP and after some research I managed to solve my problem. Below is the resolution.

In my backend FastAPI file I implemented HTTPX async (tip from @Chris). And after returning the JSON, I took the autocomplete term and added it to the first position of the JSON. Thus returning to Vue (frontend) a JSON with autocomplete and HTTPX data.

File FastAPI:

```
async def predict_question(websocket: WebSocket):
 await manager.connect(websocket)
 input_text = await websocket.receive_text()
 if not input_text:
  await manager.send_personal_message(json.dumps([]), websocket)
 else:
  autocomplete_text = text_gen.generate_text(input_text)
  autocomplete_text = re.sub(r"[\([{})\]]", "", autocomplete_text)
  autocomplete_text = autocomplete_text.split()
  autocomplete_text = autocomplete_text[0:2]
  resp = client.build_request("GET", 'www.description_url_search_='+input_text+'')
  r = await client.send(resp)
  datajson = r.json()
  datajson.insert(0, ' '.join(autocomplete_text))
  await manager.send_personal_message(json.dumps(datajson), websocket)
```

In the Autocomplete.vue file I made small changes.
First I merged the EstepeJson.vue file into Autocomplete.vue, especially the json reading part in the html.
Second, in the data: function(){} I added one more object, called myJson: [].

Third, in the receiveText method I changed the way to receive data from the websocket. Since now I have JSON.parse to convert event.data to JSON. Then I use the shift method to take the first position in the json and remove this data from the file. And finally, return the json to the myjson variable.

File Autocomplete.vue:

```
<template>
<div class="pad-container">
  <div tabindex="1" @focus="setCaret" class="autocomplete-container">
    <span @input="sendText" @keypress="preventInput" ref="editbar" class="editable" contenteditable="true"></span>
    <span class="placeholder" data-ondeleteId="#editx" contenteditable="false">{{autoComplete}}</span>    
  </div>
</div>
<div v-for="regList in myJson" :key="regList" class="container" >
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Documento</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="countryList in regList[2]" :key="countryList">
        <td style="visibility: visible">{{ countryList}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
...
data: function() {
    return {
      autoComplete: "",
      maxChars: 75,
      connection: null, 
      myJson: []
    }
  },
.....
...
    receiveText(event) {
      let result = JSON.parse(event.data)
      this.autoComplete = result.shift();
      this.myJson = result
    }
</script>
```