# How do I make two parallel, asynchronous calls using jQuery/FastAPI so that neither waits on the other?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, fastapi

I have a simple chat application written using FastAPI in Python and jQuery.  The user enters a question into form, and a response is returned from the server.  However, I also need to send the user message to a separate process that takes a long time (say, querying a database).  I don't want the user to have to wait for that separate process to complete, but I have been unable to get that to work.  I've tried all sorts of variations of Promise and await, but nothing works.  Here is a toy example that demonstrates the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#message-form').submit(async function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                    const input_message = $('#message-form input[name=message]').val()

                    $('#message-list').append('<li><strong>' + input_message + '</strong></li>');

                    side_track(input_message);

                    const response = await fetch('/submit_message', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: JSON.stringify({ message: input_message }),
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    });

                    // Reset the message input field
                    $('#message-form')[0].reset();

                    const newMessage = document.createElement('li');
                    $('#message-list').append(newMessage);
                    const stream = response.body;

                    const reader = stream.getReader();
                    const decoder = new TextDecoder();

                    const { value, done } = await reader.read();

                    const message = JSON.parse(decoder.decode(value)).message;
                    newMessage.innerHTML += message

   
            });
        });

        async function side_track(question) {
            const response = fetch('/side_track', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: JSON.stringify({ message: question }),
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    });
            alert('Getting questions')
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="message-list">
        <li>Message list.</li>
        <!-- Existing messages will be inserted here -->
    </ul>
    <form id="message-form" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

And the corresponding Python:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

class MessageInput(BaseModel):
    message: str


@app.post("/side_track")
async def side_track(message_data: MessageInput):
    import time
    time.sleep(10)
    return {"status": "ok"}


@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

async def random_numbers():
    import random
    import asyncio
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(.1)  # Wait for 1 second
        yield random.randint(1, 10)

@app.post("/submit_message")
async def submit_message(message_data: MessageInput):
    from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
    async for number in random_numbers():
        return jsonable_encoder({'message': number})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

In the example above, the user has to wait the full 10 seconds for `side_track` to complete before displaying the message returned from `submit_message`. I want the message from `submit_message` (which doesn't take any time to process) to display immediately, and the response from `side_track` to be handled separately whenever it completes, without tying up the program.

EDIT:  I modified the toy program to more accurately demonstrate the asynchronous generator that responds to `submit_message` and make it easier to replicate the problem.

Comment: You could use `websockets` instead. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70996841/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74639030/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70626324/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71738644/17865804) for more details and examples.

Comment: I took your advice and rewrote the entire application using websockets, and I still have the exact same problem.  I'm not sure that the toy example above properly captures the issue, but it does indeed lock every time.  I'll see if I can improve the example.

Comment: `time.sleep()` is blocking the event loop, as it is called within an `async def` endpoint. If you really need to call a `sleep()` function inside an `async def` endpoint, you should rather use `await asyncio.sleep()`. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details.

Comment: @Chris, thank you for that, you saved me a lot of time in pointless debugging.  Of course, in the real code there isn't a ```time.sleep()```, but instead a long running code block, so there may still be an issue.  But I bet a ton of my debugging has given false conclusions due to using ```time.sleep()``` in the toy example.

Comment: _"in the real code there isn't a `time.sleep()`, but instead a long running code block..."_. In that case, you should either define the `/side_track` endpoint with normal `def` instead of `async def`, or execute the long-running task in an external `ThreadPool` or `ProcessPool` (depending on the nature of the task) and `await` it. Please have a look at the linked answer above for more details and examples.

Comment: Yes, that did do it.  I had to change ```side_track``` not be async, as well as the functions it called, both in javascript and python.  Then I had to ```fetch.then().then()```.  But it's actually working.  I am eternally grateful, I have been chasing this solution for many hours.