# FastAPI Websocket documentation example failing to run (403 error)

Tags: python, reactjs, websocket, fastapi

I am trying to run the example in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/). I have modified it by extracting the body and putting it in a React `Socket` component. The fastapi server part is unchanged.

The app seems to load fine but when I click connect I get a 403 error

Here is the component

```
const Socket = () => {
  var ws = null
  function connect (event) {
    ws = new WebSocket(
      'ws://localhost:8000/items'
    )
    ws.onmessage = function (event) {
      var messages = document.getElementById('messages')
      var message = document.createElement('li')
      var content = document.createTextNode(event.data)
      message.appendChild(content)
      messages.appendChild(message)
    }
    event.preventDefault()
  }

  function sendMessage (event) {
    var input = document.getElementById('messageText')
    ws.send(input.value)
    input.value = ''
    event.preventDefault()
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>WebSocket Chat</h1>
      <form action='' onsubmit={sendMessage}>
        <label>
          Item ID:{' '}
          <input type='text' id='itemId' autocomplete='off' value='foo' />
        </label>
        <label>
          Token:{' '}
          <input
            type='text'
            id='token'
            autocomplete='off'
            value='some-key-token'
          />
        </label>
        <button onClick={connect}>Connect</button>
        <br></br>
        <label>
          Message: <input type='text' id='messageText' autocomplete='off' />
        </label>
        <button>Send</button>
      </form>
      <ul id='messages'></ul>
      <script></script>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Socket
```

My React App posts other requests with `axios` without issues so I am not sure, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70996841/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74639030/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780637/17865804) for working examples using `websockets` in FastAPI.